# "error: (-215) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) " error while matching to template in open cv and numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Below error code is coming when i am executing the  given code on python 2.7

error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1102: error: (-215) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function cv::matchTemplate

not fixed by:

this given solution 
img.astype(np.float32)
img.astype(np.uint8)

code :

```
import cv2

list1=[]
grid1=[]
img=cv2.imread('index.jpeg')
C,H,W=img.shape[::-1]
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert color to gray scale
ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(gray,47,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #removing text threshold
_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(thresh[:,0:H,],cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i in range(len(contours)):
               perimeter=cv2.arcLength(contours[i],True)

               if perimeter > 150 and perimeter <200 :
                  #cv2.drawContours(img,contours,i,(0,255,0),2)
                  list1.append(i)

for x in list1:
    M=cv2.moments(contours[x])
    cx=int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy=int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    cropped=img[cy-4:cy+40,cx-40:cx+40]
    w,h,c=cropped.shape
    for i in range(10):
               template=cv2.imread("no."+str(i)+".png")
               result=cv2.matchTemplate(cropped,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
               min_val,max_val,min_loc,max_loca=cv2.minMAXLoc(result)
               if(max_val>0.9):
                  grid1.append(i)


print grid1
print list1
cv2.imshow("orignal",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyALLWindows()
```

Comment: still not fixed by typecasting it to float or int

Comment: It could also be a problem with the number of dimensions?

Comment: yes that's what i find out but unable to resolve this as the given code is working with other image of big size